# Send ActionMailer from external ruby file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, external, actionmailer

i want to make a cronjob which execute a specific ruby file in the script directory of my rails app. how can i achieve, that i can execute an actionmailer to use deliver? how do i get this mailer into this ruby file?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping the part about creating a task in crontab, here is what you can do:

1. Create a rake task, in lib/tasks, which sends that email and invoke the rake task from your cron job. I have done this and this works, pretty well for me.
2. Load the Rails environment explicitly in your ruby script. I do this in some daemons.
   You can do something like this :

   ```
   require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/application"
   Rails.application.require_environment!
   ```
3. Use the rails runner. `rails runner -h` will give you the necessary information